# what will I need to return for list and do I need code for edge case duplicate?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have the following `ListNode` class:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

I wrote the following code with the aim of removing any duplicates from a linked list:

```
def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:      
    if head == None: 
        return None 
    if head.next == None: 
        return head 
    curr = head 
    nex = head.next 
    while nex: 
        if head.val == nex.val: 
            curr.next = nex.next
        curr = nex.next
        nex = curr.next
```

Questions:

1. What do I return at the end? Is it 'head' or 'curr' or something else? And why?- I know that I want the output to be a linked list of the input but with duplicates removed; so does it make sense to return the head of the linked list? But when I do this, I don't quite get the expected results, namely [1,1,2,2,3,3] -> [1,2,3,3]; which leads me to my next question...
2. Do I need to write an edge case for when there is a duplicate right at the end of the linked list? As I don't believe my code below deals with this -- am I right?

Comment: Your examples show lists that are sorted, and thus always have duplicates sitting *next to eachother*. Must we assume the list is sorted?

Comment: Also, what is the `self` argument for `deleteDuplicates`? You never reference it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your list is always sorted, so that any duplicates are always sitting next to each other in the list.

There are two issues in your `while` loop:

1. You should compare the values from the two *adjacent* nodes, but your code is always comparing the next value with the head node's value. So change:

   ```
   if head.val == nex.val:
   ```

   to

   ```
   if curr.val == nex.val:
   ```
2. Your code is skipping nodes by doing `curr = nex.next`. This means that `curr` will never be `nex`. This also has as effect that the next statement may be an invalid reference, as `curr` might be `None`. So change:

   ```
   curr = nex.next
   ```

   to

   ```
   curr = nex
   ```
3. When you detect a duplicate, only `nex` should move to the next node. `curr` should stay where it is, as it may have more than one duplicate to deal with. So the above assignment to `curr` should only happen when you *don't* have a duplicate.

The corrected `while` loop is as follows:

```
while nex:
    if curr.val == nex.val: 
        curr.next = nex.next
    else:
        curr = nex
    nex = curr.next
```

### What to return

Since your function seems to be designed to *return* a `ListNode`, just make sure to *always* return `head`. So add that statement also after the `while` loop.

In my opinion it shouldn't have been necessary for this function to return the head node, since the value of `head` will *never* change by this function. So the caller already knows the value.

NB: you don't need to deal specifically with this case:

```
if head.next == None: 
   return head
```

This case will just mean that the `while` loop will not have a single iteration. As said above, just add a return statement at the very end of the function, and then you can drop the above `if` block:

```
return head
```

Comment: Thank you very much trincot, your explanation is very clear and I understand all of it. I really appreciate the time you put in writing the comments. Cheers, Patrick